# Android drawerlayout with Submenu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to do the drawer layout with submenu. but that submenu should load as a new layout. not the expandable listview or expandable recycler.

But currently I have hide the linearlayout to open the submeu like below code.

This is the drawer_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includeLayoutDrawer"
        layout="@layout/navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is included navigation_drawer layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_menu"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--profile-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerM"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profPic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/gap_activity"
            android:src="@drawable/img_menu_avator" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/gap_activity"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gap_small"
                android:text="@string/distributor"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_menu"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/separator" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <!--menu items-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_large">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!--my property-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/home"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_menu_item"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_icon_sel"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_large">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_menu_avator" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_activity"
                        android:text="@string/d_home"
                        android:textColor="@color/veryDarkGrey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/normal" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_menu"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/separator" />

                <!--connections-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/addNewWorkShop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_menu_item"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_icon_sel"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_large">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_menu_avator" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_activity"
                        android:text="@string/d_addnew_workshop"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/normal" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_menu"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/separator" />
                <!--message-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/myProfile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_menu_item"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_icon_sel"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_large">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_menu_avator" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_activity"
                        android:text="@string/d_my_profile"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/normal" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_menu"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/separator" />
                <!--alerts-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/myTarget"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_menu_item"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_icon_sel"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_large">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_menu_avator" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_activity"
                        android:text="@string/d_my_target"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/normal" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_menu"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/separator" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/subMenu"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/width_menu"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left|start"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/back"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_menu_item"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_icon_sel"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_large">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_menu_avator" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_activity"
                        android:text="Back"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/normal" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_menu"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/separator" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/test"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_menu_item"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_icon_sel"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_large">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_menu_avator" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_activity"
                        android:text="Back"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/normal" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_menu"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/separator" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/test1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_menu_item"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_icon_sel"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_large">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_menu_avator" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/gap_activity"
                        android:text="Back"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/normal" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/width_menu"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/separator" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout
```

Inside the drawer class I have written the code for hide the linearlayout and show the submenu linearlayout like below code.

```
mBinding.includeLayoutDrawer.home.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (getFragment() instanceof HomeFragment) {
            //already has
        } else {
            Utils.replaceFragmentInActivity(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
HomeFragment.newInstance(),
                    R.id.contentFrame, false);
        }

        closeDrawer();
    });

    mBinding.includeLayoutDrawer.myProfile.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        mBinding.includeLayoutDrawer.menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mBinding.includeLayoutDrawer.subMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    });

    mBinding.includeLayoutDrawer.back.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        mBinding.includeLayoutDrawer.menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mBinding.includeLayoutDrawer.subMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    });
```

But I need to open the submenu like, 
when I click the drawer menu button then the drawer will open from left to right slider. then If I click any content to open the submenu then have to open the submenu like main drawer open. Then If I click back button then it should go back to the main content drawer.

Actually I am expecting like this Shell Investor & Media app drawer.

[enter link description here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobgen.shellir&hl=en)

Thanks